# regex to match one string and negate the other

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I need a regex to match `Test<` string only from `Test<OKAY>` and it should not match `Test<?>`

```
Test<?>  // shouldn't match
Test<OKAY> // should match
```

I tried `Test<[^?]` but it matches `Test<O` instead of `Test<` from `Test<OKAY>`

How do I fix this?

Comment: It's not clear what the conditions are, do you need `OKAY` to be in the brackets in order to match initial the `TEST<`, or do you need whatever is contained in the brackets to not have `?`, or what?

Comment: Yes. OKAY is in brackets. suppose you have a file which has these two lines. I need a regex to match only the second one and the word OKAY could be anything . You can have any word in place of OKAY.

Comment: ...As long as the word doesn't contain question marks? Is that the qualifying factor?

Comment: Yes. I want all lines containing Test< where Test< is not followed by ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I figured out that I could use Negative lookahead worked. You can post an answer if you have different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `Test<`, you need positive lookahead for non-question-mark characters, followed by `>` to indicate the end of the brackets:

```
Test<(?=[^?]+>)
```

https://regex101.com/r/gxpq3E/1

Answer (score 1):

Use a look ahead:

```
Test<(?=OKAY>)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/e4ZoPCH3Yu).

Answer (score 0):

Test<(?!\?) works

Using negative lookahead here.

?! = not followed by \?